# API limit for Google Android Speech recognition

Tags: android, android-speech-api

Android has a speech recognition API well documented over [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html). Now, if I plan to integrate this in my application, I want to know what is limit to the API calls/requests that I can make to the Google server using Speech API.

Is this commercially free to use or does Google provide usage plans for the same. Does anyone know about pricing etc?

Please let me know in case you have used Speech API for Android only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used this API, but as far as I can tell, if the Service doesn't request credentials like an API Key, there's probably not a great way for them to track or limit your usage.

Since you're launching a Google Intent for speech recognition, it's actually google making the request to their own Services for a recognition.

I doubt there are any limits or costs, unless you've heard about otherwise.

Comment: If you compare this API with other google API services like Maps, Youtube etc you will find that Maps does have a limit usage, API key etc mentioned when we activate it using API console...so in that case do u think Speech API has something like that ..as I don't seem to find it in the list of services in the API console

Answer (score -1):

Yeah!! Google speech API it`s free, you just need subscribe to [chromium-dev](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).Create an app in developer [console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), the APIs below are only visible to people subscribed to that group.

Good luck!!...(Y).